# Display image created by OpenCV on Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

Im trying to convert a image to gray with OpenCV with this native method in JNI

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_android_OpenCV_gray(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
        int width  = pImage->width;
    int height =  pImage->height;
    IplImage *dst = cvCreateImage( cvSize( width, height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvCvtColor( pImage, dst, CV_RGB2GRAY );

}
```

but  i dont know how to display the image on Android

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the image to java and handle the visualization there, see: http://jataka.hu/rics/nxt_android_opencv/index.html